# Compile error with inner class (bracket expected)

Tags: java, inner-classes, curly-brackets

I have an inner listener class in my program. The compiler signals an error at the first line below and says '{' expected. I can't figure out what's wrong. I revised all my brackets and there's no problem. Here's my inner class:

```
private class Listener implements Action Listener
{
    public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(i==1 && field.equalsIgnoreCase("red"))
        {
            i++;
            label.setText("Enter color number" + i);
            field.setText("");
            return;
        }
        if(i==2 && field.equalsIgnoreCase("white"))
        {
            i++;
            label.setText("Enter color number" + i);
            field.setText("");
            return;
        }
        if(i==3 && field.equalsIgnoreCase("yellow"))
        {
            i++;
            label.setText("Enter color number" + i);
            field.setText("");
            return;
        }
        if(i==4 && field.equalsIgnoreCase("green"))
        {
            i++;
            label.setText("Enter color number" + i);
            field.setText("");
            return;
        }
        if(i==5 && field.equalsIgnoreCase("blue"))
        {
            field.setVisible(false);
            label.setText("Congratulations - your memory is perfect");
            return;
        }

        field.setVisible(false);
        label.setText("Sorry - wrong color. Eat more antioxidants");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Action Listener
```

is one word

```
ActionListener
```

Comment: Thanks! (and thanks to the post above)
Now I have another error:
"AndrewSidhomProg7.Listener is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener
  private class Listener implements ActionListener"

Comment: Never mind. Solved it. I had ActionPerformed instead of actionPerformed. Really tired tonight and trying to get my assignment done in time.

Answer (score 3):

It should be `implements ActionListener` without the space between `Action` and `Listener`.